# Back Button from Main Activity - Normal Behvior?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

If I press the back button from my main activity I get a black screen. Is this normal behavior ? To get round this I have put in the following code - is this an ok work around ?

```
public void onBackPressed() {

return;
}
```

EDIT

Here is the manifest in case it is wrong :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.example.DatabaseImport"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailView"
    android:label="@string/detail_label"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: try with `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a normal behavious.
Do you have an initial activity from which you start your "main" activity?
Do you have any key listeners?

It sounds like you have another activity calling your "main" activity and clicking back in the "main" activity goes back to the unfinished initial activity.

EDIT:
From your edit I see you don't have an additional activity before the main one, so the only assumption is that you're doing something wrong in onStop / onPause or onDestroy. Please paste these.

Comment: Hi IncrediApp. I don't implement either onStop / onPause or onDestroy.

Comment: Sorry, but I think we went over all the possibilities without seeing your code... If you feel safe to paste your activity code in here we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Back button calls `finish()` by default. There could be problem in `onPause()` in your Activity or in `onStart()` and `onResume()` of Activity that started yours.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal behavior. Pressing back button in main activity should take you to the home screen.

are you sure it's the first activity? your manifest should look something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".yourApp.YourMainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `onPause` and `onStop` callbacks as light as possible. May be some thing in these methods is causing the delay.